# Complex numbers converge if their absolute values and arguments converge

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, exponential-function, absolute-value

Let the sequence $\{z_n\}_{n>0}$ and $w \not=0$ be such that $|z_n| \to |w|$ and $\operatorname{Arg}(z_n) \to \operatorname{Arg}(w)$. Show that $z_n \to w$.

**My proof**: $z_n= |z_n|e^{i \arg(z_n)} \to |w|e^{i \arg(w)}=w$.

Does $\arg(z_n) \to \arg(w)$ if $\operatorname{Arg}(z_n) \to \operatorname{Arg}(w)$?

Comment: If $Arg$ is the principal argument, why do you use $z_n=|z_n|e^{iarg(z_n)}$ instead of $z_n=|z_n|e^{iArg(z_n)}$?

Comment: Not really. But you can take $Arg(z_n)$ and $Arg(w)$

Comment: If you want a solid proof from scratch, assume $\big| |z_n| - |w| \big| < \epsilon$ and $\big| \mathop{\rm Arg}(z_n) - \mathop{\rm Arg}(w) \big| < \epsilon$, and see if that implies a bound on $| z_n-w |$ that goes to $0$ as $\epsilon\to0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\left| e^{i Arg(z_n)} -e^{i Arg(w)} \right|=\left| e^{i \left( Arg(z_n)-Arg(w)\right)} -1 \right|$$